# If the limit of the difference of two random variables goes to 0, are the limits of their expectations the same?

Tags: probability, limits, probability-theory, expected-value

I have two discrete random variables $X_n$ and $Y_n$ and a relation between them that looks like, for $n\geq 1$
$$X_n = a_nP\{A_n\} + Y_n P\{{A_n}^c\},$$
where $A_n$ is an event and $a_n$ depends on $n$ but is not a random variable. The thing is, the sequence of probabilities $P\{A_n\}$ go to $0$ as $n\to \infty$, so I believe this means that $X_n$ converges to $Y_n$ in some meaningful way, but I'm not sure which. From here, can one conclude that
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} E\{X_n\} = \lim_{n\to\infty} E\{Y_n\}?$$
I'm sorry if this is very elementary. I have difficulties getting my head around limits and expectations.

Comment: In fact, we don't need the absolute value signs; I have actually found that $\lim_{n\to\infty} (X_n - Y_n) = 0$.

Comment: To clarify the limit is taken on a common probability space?

Comment: @AlexR. Yes, sorry about that. The probability space is the same.

Comment: Which kind limit is $\lim_{n\to\infty} |X_n-Y_n| = 0$? Random variables have multiple types of convergence. Some implies the convergence of expectation. But not all

Comment: @user251257 Is it enough if they converge to the same limit in probability? I'm trying to figure out right now if they converge to the same limit a.s. but I'm pretty sure we at least have the "in probability" kind of convergence.

Comment: not without additional assumption

Comment: @user251257 Hmm would the implication hold if we have convergence a.s.?

Comment: not without additional assumption

Comment: Okay I'll try to add more information in the question

Comment: What do you know about $a_n$? Does it goes to 0? If it's growing, then this might not converge.

Comment: @DaviBarreira The sequence $a_n$ converges. I think that we can just apply the tower rule?

Comment: Sorry, you still need $Y_n$ converging, otherwise you get the problem I described in the beginning of my answer. Does it converge? And if it does, in what way? Probability, pointwise, uniformly?

Comment: I've updated the answer for the case that $Y_n$ converges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $X_n = a_n P(A_n) + Y_nP(A_n^c)$, we know by the linearity of the expected value that:
$$E(X_n) = E(a_n P(A_n) + Y_nP(A_n^c))= E(a_n P(A_n)) + E(Y_nP(A_n^c)) =$$
$$
=a_nP(A_n) + P(A_n^c)E(Y_n)$$

If $a_n \rightarrow a$ and if $Y_n$ converges (note that this is necessary for the limit to exist), then
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}E(X_n) =\lim_{n \to \infty}a_nP(A_n) + P(A_n^c)E(Y_n)=
\lim_{n \to \infty}a_nP(A_n) + \lim_{n \to \infty}P(A_n^c)E(Y_n)
$$
Since $P(A_n) \rightarrow 0$, we conclude that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}E(X_n) =\lim_{n \to \infty}P(A_n^c)\lim_{n \to \infty}E(Y_n)=\lim_{n \to \infty}E(Y_n)
$$

Comment: I see that you have updated your question. I will modify my answer.